# MvvmCross vnext - Plugin problems

Tags: plugins, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I've been using MvvmCross v1 for a while now, & I find it really useful & not too hard to use! So I bit the bullet & decided to use vnext for our next project. All was well until I tried to use a plugin, and it crashes with the following output -

```
2013-03-21 18:14:27.121 MyApp[85942:11903] mvx: Diagnostic:   0,00 Setup: Text serialization start
2013-03-21 18:14:27.124 MyApp[85942:11903] mvx: Diagnostic:   0,03 Setup: PlatformServices start
2013-03-21 18:14:27.125 MyApp[85942:11903] mvx: Diagnostic:   0,03 Setup: ViewModelFramework start
2013-03-21 18:14:27.126 MyApp[85942:11903] mvx: Diagnostic:   0,03 Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
2013-03-21 18:14:27.127 MyApp[85942:11903] mvx: Diagnostic:   0,03 Setup: App start

Unhandled Exception:
0   MyApp                      0x00079b12 mono_handle_exception_internal_first_pass + 3058
1   MyApp                      0x0007b1e2 mono_handle_exception_internal + 1602
2   MyApp                      0x0007bd2f mono_handle_exception + 47
3   MyApp                      0x000bce22 mono_x86_throw_exception + 306
4   ???                                 0x07986f8f 0x0 + 127430543
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.MvxBasePluginManager.ExceptionWrappedLoadPlugin (System.Type) <IL 0x00002, 0x0001f>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.MvxBasePluginManager.EnsureLoaded<T> () <IL 0x00030, 0x0008c>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Share.PluginLoader.EnsureLoaded () <IL 0x00008, 0x00029>
at MyApp.Core.BaseApp.InitialisePlugins () [0x00000] in /Users/franklyn/Documents/Programming/MyApp/MyApp.Core/App.cs:42
```

It happens whenever I try lo load a plugin which has a "Touch" project element, others such as the JsonLocalisation plugin which don't have, load fine.

If anyone else has come across this & knows the fix, I'd be very pleased to hear from them.

Comment: Have you tried stepping into it while in debug mode and narrow it down as to where exactly it breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android, plugins are loaded just because they are there - they are files and can be loaded through `Assembly.Load`

For iOS, plugins cannot be loaded this way because of the Ahead-Of-Time compilation requirement.

To solve this, all platform specific plugins in iOS have to be registered during setup.

You can see this code in `AddPluginLoaders` in `Setup` in all the samples - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.UI.Touch/Setup.cs

```
protected override void AddPluginsLoaders(MvxLoaderPluginRegistry registry)
{
    registry.AddConventionalPlugin<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Touch.Plugin>();
    registry.AddConventionalPlugin<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.Touch.Plugin>();
    registry.AddConventionalPlugin<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Touch.Plugin>();
    base.AddPluginsLoaders(registry);
}
```

---

Overall, the plugin mechanism is much better than the old `v1` code because it means less unwanted code is included in your app and because it is extensible.

---

For a recent discussion on why `Assembly.Load` cannot be used in iOS, see http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/7882 - I have tried to avoid this step.

Comment: Thanks Stuart - I got it running now. I knew about the AOT requirement, I just hadn't figured out how you were initialising the plugins. I have another question now re initialising the GeoLocationWatcher - I'll do it as another question.